# Facebook-like Notification System

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, notifications

I wanted to create a notification system like the facebook one and thinking of the structure to realize this system.

I've two tables: `notification` (id, uid, query, date) and `notification_unread` (id, nid, uid, date).

I tought to use this the following way:
If I make a comment somewhere, I'll add: my uid, $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], NOW() to `notification`.

With `notification_unread` I wanted to insert data of posts that hasn't been read yet. In this case `nid` should refer to the notification id. And only if there may be another new post, data will be inserted in this table. Everytime something has been seen by the user, I'll delete the specific entry from this table.

Well, however I couldn't really figure out, if this approach (including DB Design) of me is somewhere somehow "the wrong" or "too complicated" way 
and I couldn't figure out to realize this, because I can't think of a logical way WHEN and HOW to insert data to `notification_unread`. For instance I don't want to notify myself that I made a new post, after I made it. But I guess I'd still have to insert data to the table?

So, the thing is that I'm trying to insert as much data as needed and realize this most effecient.

I hope you could follow me and would really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: I'm intrigued as to the thought process that led you to thinking that two tables were better than a single Notification table with a field for read or unread

Comment: Because a message having been read is a fact that is distinct from a message having been created?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it may seem very simple & clean solution but its a downfall afterwards.
As podiluska pointed, its better to have a check field.

You can easily display unread one, but what will happen once a user has check it? You will have to move it in read table which will increase your disk I/O which is the slowest process in any system. You can simply query off last 5 notifications or something.

You may want to create an archive table to move old notifications to archive table. Here important thing will be to maintain that notification table since all the updates will be here. The bigger it becomes, more the performance will suffer. Its a long time effect but you might want to consider the solution now rather than later.